# How to display list items in descending order in django?

Tags: python, django

I've created a website that streams cartoons. On the first page, the user gets to see the entire list of cartoons. When clicked, a page showing the details of the cartoon as well its corresponding seasons loads. When a specific season is clicked. It shows the list of episodes that season has. Now what happens is that it displays the episodes normally, however, it shows them in a jumbled format. I want to show it in descending order. How am I supposed to go about doing that? Here are my files.
If you didn't understand this description of my problem(which you probably didn't) you can see the website for yourself http://cartoonpalace.herokuapp.com:

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from  django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import CartoonSeason, Cartoon, Episode
# Create your views here 

class CartoonListView(ListView):
    model = Cartoon
    template_name = "index.html"



class CartoonSeasonView(DetailView):
  
    model = Cartoon
    template_name = "season.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["seasons"] = CartoonSeason.objects.filter(cartoon=self.object)
        return context



class SeasonDetailView(DetailView):
  
    model = CartoonSeason
    template_name = "episode_list.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["episodes"] = Episode.objects.filter(season=self.object)
        return context



class EpisodeDetailView(DetailView):
  
    model = Episode
    template_name = "episode.html"
```

Models.py

```
# Create your models here.
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Cartoon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cover = models.URLField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_date = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    end_date = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 


class CartoonSeason(models.Model):
    cartoon = models.ForeignKey(Cartoon, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    season_cover = models.URLField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    season_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    season_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False)
    
  
  
    def __str__(self):
        return self.cartoon.name + " | " +  str(self.season_name)


class Episode(models.Model):
    season = models.ForeignKey(CartoonSeason, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    cover  = models.URLField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    published = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.number) + ": " +  self.name + " | " +  self.season.season_name +  " | " + self.season.cartoon.name
```

Episode_list.html (This shows the list of episodes the season has.)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
    {{object.season_name}} - {{object.cartoon.name}}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<main>
    <section class="cartoon-description" >
        <div class="season-head">
            <img  class="cover" src="{{object.season_cover}}" width="260px" alt="">
            <div class="cartoon-name">
                <h1>{{object.season_name}}</h1>

                <br>
                <div class="description">
                    <strong>Description:</strong>
                    
                    <p>{{object.season_description}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </section>

       


<section class="episode-list">
    {% for episode in episodes %}
    <div class="episode-item">
        
        <div class="episode-details">
            <a href="{% url 'episodes' episode.pk %}"><h3>{{episode.name}}</h3></a>
            <small>Episode No: {{episode.number}}</small>
        </div>

        
    </div>

    {% endfor %}
</section>
</main>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have more than one way to do that

one can be setting the order in the model.

```
class Episode(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    published = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-published"]
```

Notice the minus sign, it tells django to fetch the data sorted in descending order

Comment: this would work, but i want it to order based on the number field in the episode model

Comment: ok it worked, i replaced published with number